# Text colors in an NSTableColumn on highlight

Tags: cocoa, colors, nstableview, highlighting, nstablecolumn

I've got an column of cells in an NSTableView that get their text color from the app's preference plist. I want to set the text color to white when highlighted, but have been unable to figure out a good way to do this.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Text color or background color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's no easier way to do this, implement the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:` delegate method to set the cell's `textColor` to either `[NSColor alternateSelectedControlTextColor]` or `[NSColor selectedControlTextColor]` depending on whether `rowIndex` is in the table view's `selectedRowIndexes` set.

(The “selected” in “`{alternateS,s}electedControlTextColor`” refers to the control, not the text. You're using the alternate (or not alternate) text color for the selected control, which is the table view.)